# Scrape this value from a request response

Tags: python, json, python-requests, screen-scraping

unluckily i can provide only the output of the request and not the full code since it contains quite private infos, basically when printing the reuqest as text file i get a json one, something like that:

`{"redirectUrl":"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout\u0026token=EC-....."}`

How can i scrape that Paypal url? tried by doing this but it didn't worked:

```
content = checkout.text()
checkout.url = content["redirectUrl"]
```

I only get this error while doing it:

`content = checkout.text() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: what kind of object is `checkout`? is it `requests.Response`? If yes - look at `Response.json()` method and then extract key `reirectUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `requests` library, you can simply do:

```py
resp = requests.get(url=url)
content = resp.json()

redirect_url = content["redirectUrl"]
```

You can read more about the request content [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content), including the [json request content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Comment: Perfect, ty for the help!